# Tomcat Credentials

Tags: xml, tomcat

I want to start a dynamic web project directly from tomcat and I have defined the `tomcat-users.xml` file for the credentials:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users version="1.0" xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd">
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-status, admin-gui, admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

However, when I go to enter the `admin` and `admin` credentials, I cannot log in. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `tomcat-users.xml` file as follows

```
 <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
 <role rolename="admin-script"/>
 <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
 <role rolename="manager-status"/>
 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
```

Here, I have selected username="admin" & password="admin" for all roles.
I am using Tomcat v10